# How can I write a function template for all types with a particular type trait?

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, enable-if

Consider the following example:

```
struct Scanner
{
    template <typename T>
    T get();
};

template <>
string Scanner::get()
{
    return string("string");
}

template <>
int Scanner::get()
{
    return 10;
}

int main()
{
    Scanner scanner;
    string s = scanner.get<string>();
    int i = scanner.get<int>();
}
```

The `Scanner` class is used to extract tokens from some source. The above code works fine, but fails when I try to `get` other integral types like a `char` or an `unsigned int`. The code to read these types is exactly the same as the code to read an `int`. I could just duplicate the code for all other integral types I'd like to read, but I'd rather define one function template for all integral types.

I've tried the following:

```
struct Scanner
{
    template <typename T>
    typename enable_if<boost::is_integral<T>, T>::type get();
};
```

Which works like a charm, but I am unsure how to get `Scanner::get<string>()` to function again. So, how can I write code so that I can do `scanner.get<string>()` and `scanner.get<any integral type>()` and have a single definition to read all integral types?

**Update: bonus question**: What if I want to accept more than one range of classes based on some traits? For example: how should I approach this problem if I want to have three  `get` functions that accept (i) integral types (ii) floating point types (iii) strings, respectively.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
struct Scanner
{
    template <typename T>
    typename boost::enable_if<boost::is_integral<T>, T>::type get()
    {
        return 10;
    }
    template <typename T>
    typename boost::disable_if<boost::is_integral<T>, std::string>::type get()
    {
        return "string";
    }
};
```

**Update "What if I want to accept more than one range of classes based on some traits?"**

```
struct Scanner
{
    template <typename T>
    typename boost::enable_if<boost::is_integral<T>, T>::type get()
    {
        return 10;
    }

    template <typename T>
    typename boost::enable_if<boost::is_floating_point<T>, T>::type get()
    {
        return 11.5;
    }

    template <typename T>
    std::string get(
          typename boost::disable_if<boost::is_floating_point<T>, T>::type* = 0, 
          typename boost::disable_if<boost::is_integral<T>, T>::type* = 0)

    {
        return std::string("string");
    }
};
```

Comment: I would remark that you could probably use the `boost::mpl::and_` and `boost::mpl::or_` to combine the arguments in `disable_if`. +1 nonetheless :)

Comment: You could also use `ice_and` and `ice_or` from the Boost library.

Answer (score 3):

Defer to another template.  Here's the general pattern for what you want:

```
template <typename T, bool HasTrait = false>
struct scanner_impl;

template <typename T>
struct scanner_impl
{
    // Implement as though the trait is false
};

template <typename T>
struct scanner_impl<true>
{
    // Implement as though the trait is true
};

// This is the one the user uses
template <typename T>
struct scanner : scanner_impl<T, typename has_my_trait<T>::value>
{
};
```

Comment: Good idea to add indirection this way.  Maybe it would become even more flexible if you don't use a `bool`, but an `enum` as trait-switch.

Comment: @xtofl: Yep.  That would answer for the bonus question too.