# Disallow a specific function template instantiation

Tags: c++

I would like to define a template function but disallow instantiation with a particular type. Note that in general all types are allowed and the generic template works, I just want to disallow using a few specific types.

For example, in the code below I wish to prevent using `double` with the template. This doesn't actually prevent the instantiation, but just causes a linker error by not having the function defined.

```
template<typename T>
T convert( char const * in )
{ return T(); }

//this way creates a linker error
template<>
double convert<double>( char const * in );

int main()
{
    char const * str = "1234";

    int a = convert<int>( str );
    double b = convert<double>( str );
}
```

*The code is just a demonstration, obviously the convert function must do something more.*

**Question:** In the above code how can I produce a compiler error when trying to use the `convert<double>` instantiation?

---

The closest related question I can find is [How to intentionally cause a compile-time error on template instantiation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3926637/how-to-intentionally-cause-a-compile-time-error-on-template-instantiation) It deals with a class, not a function.

The reason I need to do this is because the types I wish to block will actually compile and do something with the generic version. That's however not supposed to be part of the contract of the function and may not be supported on all platforms/compilers and in future versions. Thus I'd like to prevent using it at all.

Comment: You have already done that, haven't you?

Comment: No, that gives a linker error about a missing function. That error won't tell you where the problem is either, it'll just tell you which module it is in.

Comment: You could trigger a compile-time error using `static_assert`: `template <> foo<double>(const char*) { static_assert(false, "not allowed"); }`

Comment: @edA-qa mort-ora-y: what do you understand by "disallowing instantiation"?

Comment: @evnu: This can be problematic, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5246049/572743

Comment: @Damon: Yes. Maybe one could trigger a simple compile error (like char a[0] or sth.)

Comment: @Nawaz, I differentiate between compile and link-time. Since errors  at link time are generally useless.

Comment: @envu that approach doesn't work since it is a specialize template. The error will be produced whether that version is used or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a static assert within your function call to create the proper failure during function instantiation:

```
template<typename T>
class is_double{ static const int value = false; }

template<>
class is_double<double>{ static const int value = true; }

template<typename T>
T convert( const char *argument ){
    BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT( !is_double<T>::value );
    //rest of code
}
```

And that should work within a function.

Comment: Should be `static bool const value`. :)

Comment: Ah yes. I feel silly since I use static assert in many places, somehow it just escaped my mind here.

Comment: I wish GCC could give a better error message than `invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘boost::STATIC_ASSERTION_FAILURE<false>’`  Oh well, it'll do.

Comment: I use this method now, though I've used a boost trait: `BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(!(boost::is_same<T,double>::value));`

Comment: @edA-qa mort-ora-y Ahmen to that.  But at least it hones in right where the error is happening intead of some of the other messages I've seen where there are 50 million template parameters thrown up on my screen.

Comment: C++11 now has a built in static_assert, no boost required.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a functor instead of a function:

```
template<typename T>
struct convert { 
    T operator()(char const * in) const { return T(); } 
};
template<> struct convert<double>;

int main()
{
    char const * str = "1234";

    int a = convert<int>()( str );
    double b = convert<double>()( str ); // error in this line

    return 0;
}
```

This will give you an error at the point of instantiation.

By adding helper function you will get the wanted behaviour:

```
template<typename T>
struct convert_helper { 
    T operator()(char const * in) const { return T(); } 
};
template<> struct convert_helper<double>;

template<typename T>
T convert( char const * in ) { return convert_helper<T>()( in ); }

int main()
{
    char const * str = "1234";

    int a = convert<int>( str );
    double b = convert<double>( str );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a also a good option since I already have essentially the second scheme for other reasons.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to rely on `static_assert` or make the code portable pre-C++0x, use this:

```
template<class T>
void func(){
    typedef char ERROR_in_the_matrix[std::is_same<T,double>::value? -1 : 1];
}

int main(){
  func<int>(); // no error
  func<double>(); // error: negative subscript
}
```

Comment: I didn't think `std:is_same` was available pre-C++11 (or C++0x as it was back here)

Answer (score 0):

Consider `Boost disable_if` and `Boost TypeTraits`

Take a look at [How can I write a function template for all types with a particular type trait?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537229/how-can-i-write-a-function-template-for-all-types-with-a-particular-type-trait/2537330#2537330)

**This is an example:**

```
#include <boost/type_traits.hpp>
#include <boost/utility/enable_if.hpp>

template<typename T>
T convert( char const * in, 
           typename boost::disable_if<boost::is_floating_point<T>, T>::type* = 0 )
{ return T(); }


int main()
{
    char const * str = "1234";

    int a = convert<int>( str );
    double b = convert<double>( str );
    return 0;
}
```

This is the compilation error for the string

```
double b = convert<double>( str );
```

> 1>.\simple_no_stlport.cpp(14) : error
>   C2770: invalid explicit template
>   argument(s) for 'T convert(const char
>   *,boost::disable_if,T>::type
>   *)' 1>        .\simple_no_stlport.cpp(5) : see
>   declaration of 'convert'